# Why I am not getting approximate equiprobable states in the following circuit on IBM Q simulator?

Tags: circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience

I have the following circuit which consists of symmetric modules. I compiled the circuit in IBM Quantum experience backend - ibmq_qasm_simulator, 8192 shots. The result is not equiprobable. Why? Since this is not a real machine ideally I should get same probability of 16.67%.

[image: figure]
[image: results]

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg qA[8];
qreg qB[8];
qreg qC[6];
qreg qD[6];
creg c[4];

h qA[2];
h qA[4];
x qA[6];
x qA[7];
x qB[1];
h qB[2];
h qB[4];
x qB[6];
x qB[7];
h qC[0];
h qC[2];
x qC[4];
x qC[5];
h qD[0];
h qD[2];
x qD[4];
x qD[5];
cx qA[2],qA[3];
cx qA[4],qA[5];
h qA[6];
cx qB[2],qB[3];
cx qB[4],qB[5];
h qB[6];
cx qC[0],qC[1];
cx qC[2],qC[3];
h qC[4];
cx qD[0],qD[1];
cx qD[2],qD[3];
h qD[4];
cx qA[6],qA[7];
cx qB[6],qB[7];
cx qC[4],qC[5];
cx qD[4],qD[5];
x qA[0];
ccx qA[6],qA[0],qA[4];
ccx qB[6],qB[0],qB[4];
ccx qA[7],qA[1],qA[5];
ccx qB[7],qB[1],qB[5];
x qA[6];
x qA[7];
x qB[6];
x qB[7];
ccx qA[6],qA[0],qA[2];
ccx qB[6],qB[0],qB[2];
ccx qA[7],qA[1],qA[3];
ccx qB[7],qB[1],qB[3];
cx qA[2],qA[3];
cx qA[4],qA[5];
cx qB[2],qB[3];
cx qB[4],qB[5];
ccx qA[3],qC[4],qC[2];
ccx qB[3],qC[5],qC[3];
x qC[4];
x qC[5];
ccx qA[3],qC[4],qC[0];
id qA[5];
ccx qB[3],qC[5],qC[1];
id qA[5];
cx qC[0],qC[1];
cx qC[2],qC[3];
ccx qA[5],qD[4],qD[2];
ccx qB[5],qD[5],qD[3];
x qD[4];
x qD[5];
ccx qA[5],qD[4],qD[0];
ccx qB[5],qD[5],qD[1];
cx qD[0],qD[1];
cx qD[2],qD[3];
measure qC[1] -> c[3];
measure qC[3] -> c[2];
measure qD[1] -> c[1];
measure qD[3] -> c[0];
```

Comment: Are you able to check your expected result by running this on a statevector simulator?

Comment: I tested on IBM quantum experience ibmq_qasm_simulator backend. I do not have idea about "statevector simulator".

Comment: The statevector simulator will give you the final state vector of the circuit, you can load it by using `statevector_simulator` instead of `qasm_simulator`. This way you can check if your circuit is actually doing what you think it is

Comment: I am not able to find statevector_simulator in available backends (in https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/). Where can I find that option?

Comment: `Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104884/discussion-between-adam-levine-and-met927).

Comment: @AdamLevine: What is a purpose of the circuit?

Comment: I have qA[0]qA[1] = 01, qB[0]qB[1] = 10. Initially I am permuting  qA[0]qA[1] and then qB[0]qB[1]. Later I am permuting   qA[0]qB[0] and qA[1]qB[1]. It is a part of binary voting protocol where qA[0], qA[1], qB[0], qB[1] are votes.

Comment: @MartinVesely I am not understanding why result is not uniform on simulator.

Comment: @AdamLevine: I tried to run the circuit and made several modification but without any success. Do you have any paper the circuit is based on? I need to understand what is behind firstly because I am not familiar with *binary voting protocol*.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You might have an issue in your circuit. I believe the first X gate on line qB1 should actually be on line qB0 to be symmetric with the upper block.

Maybe you can also try to move those X gates just before the two controlled gates  as they act on the first and third qubit you measure but not on the second and fourth ones (in descending order).

Comment: I guess that is not a problem. Even if I correct that, I am getting the same problem.

Comment: check my edited answer to see it that helps